# jQuery ui - cloned code not responding to sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

I'm working on a page that requires constant HTML elements to be added, removed and sorted from the DOM. I have a hidden DIV that contains all the blocks of code that I use clone() on and append it to the DOM. sortable() works on list-items already in the DOM, but not on DOM injected list-items after the DOM is done loading. I have the following list, simplified for example purpose:

```
<ul class="sprite-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="icon.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="icon.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sprite-add">
        <a href="#">Add</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use the following jQuery code:

```
$('ul.sprite-list').sortable({
    items: 'li:not(.sprite-add)',
    containment: 'parent',
    opacity: 0.7
}).disableSelection();
```

With that list hardcoded in the page, it works great. But after I cloned the same list into the DOM I can't seem to drag & drop them.

I've read and seen [working examples](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/VxYmw/1/) of sortable() working live. I also saw people recommend using [.sortable('refresh')](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-refresh). So I tried

```
$('ul.sprite-list').sortable('refresh');
```

or

```
$.fn.sortable('refresh');
```

but all without success. What am I missing here?

**edit**: I noticed after injecting the cloned code, the list does have the class *ui-sortable* which all sortable lists get.

**edit 2**: I don't know if it's relevant but I use a seperate function to get the cloned elements:

```
function cloneElement(element){
    var container = $('#sprite-clone');

    if(element == 'generationContainer'){
        return container.find('.sprite-generation-container').clone(true);
    }
    else if(element == 'groupContainer'){
        return container.find('.sprite-group-container').clone(true);
    }
    else if(element == 'sprite'){
        return container.find('>li:first').clone(true);
    }
    else if(element == 'customForm'){
        return container.find('.customForm').clone(true);
    }
}
```

Then when it's needed I use var generationContainer = cloneElement('generationContainer');
I'm not sure if that affects anything though.

Comment: `$('ul.sprite-list').sortable('refresh');` should work as long as you call it every time something new is added. Are you getting any errors or anything?

Comment: When you clone the list, are you cloning it with the event handlers as well? That is, are you setting the `withDataAndEvents` and `deepWithDataAndEvents` arguments to `true`? http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @MrOBrian Not getting any errors. And I indeed did call it everytime I add something new.

Comment: @Zhihao I didn't set those 2, but now I did. Nothing changed. They still don't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the working examples code doesn't clone, but add new content, so its a different thing.

Since I cannot see the rest of the code, then I'm only theorizing. Fix could be done by recalling sortable. So if you would put your sortable code inside a function, call it on document ready and then again when a element as been added.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BWkFp/**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sprite-list">
    <li>
        test 1
    </li>
    <li>
        test 2
    </li>
    <li>
        test 3
    </li>
    <li class="sprite-add">
        <a href="#">Add</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
MakeUlSortable = function () {
    $('ul.sprite-list').sortable({
        items: 'li:not(.sprite-add)',
        opacity: 0.7
    }).disableSelection();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    MakeUlSortable();
});

$('.sprite-add a').click(function () {
    $(this).before($('.sprite-list li:first-child').clone());
    MakeUlSortable();
    return false;
});
```

Hope you get my point. This code works well for me :)

Comment: Good thinking. But unfortunately nothing changed. I'm trying to think of a way to debug this, but it's really hard.

Comment: I found the answer. Mostly because of this. I did exactly this, but I didn't initialize it by just executing MakeUlSortable(). So only after inserting content I used MakeUlSortable() and it works! I'm still trying to figure out why it acts like this. It just doesn't make any sense to me. Thanks a lot Kalle!